# Changing Facebook API event subscribe only too run when a certain like button is clicked?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, api, facebook

Using the Facebook API how can i change the event subscribe script to run only when a certian like button has been clicked? I will have many separate like buttons on my page and this code:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) {
  // codey stuff
});
```

Will go off if any are clicked.. right? How do i change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't subscribe to only certain events, but if you check the `response` variable you get in the callback you'll get the URL of the object for which an edge was just created. From there, you can determine if it's the object you're interested in, and handle it accordingly.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create', function(response) 
{               
    if (response == "<whatever>") {
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

EDIT: Here's a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JimmySawczuk/m48Du/).